# index array with .map doesn't work on nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

Hi everyone I try to index with map a json array. But it doesn't work properly. I think my code is not correct.

my code :

```
var  entireHTMLssssq = lloopmois.map(result, index => `<div id=${index}  style="position: absolute;">  <b style="position:absolute;top:-6px;left:2px"> ${result} </b>    </div>`).join('')
```

Can you tell me the right syntax please.

Comment: What is `lloopmois`? What is `result`?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] (include sample input, use the live demo feature in the question editor) and a *clear problem statement* ("doesn't work properly" tells us very little, tells us what the difference between what you get and what you expect is).

Comment: @Jeto is the json array.

Comment: indent your code for better readability

Comment: @mataka — A JSON array? So `var lloopmois = "[1,2,3]";`? You need to parse the JSON to turn it into a JavaScript array before you can call `map` on it.

Comment: Yes @Quentin. From a file

Comment: Is already parse

Comment: @mataka — If it is already parsed, then it is no longer JSON. (And to repeat myself: provide a live demo with sample data).

Comment: Nina gave to me the right syntax @Quentin Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a parenthesis around the parameters by using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), if you have more than one parameter.

```
lloopmois.map((result, index) => ...)
//            ^             ^
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with brackets `()` and `return`for the map function.

`array.map((result, index)=>{return ...})` is the right syntax

```
var  entireHTMLssssq = lloopmois.map((result, index) => {
return `<div id=${index} style="position: absolute;">  <b 
style="position:absolute;top:-6px;left:2px"> ${result} </b>    
</div>`}).join('')
```